# Tips to get USA Visa approval for Brazilian Girlfriend

Tags: visas, visa-refusals

My Girlfriend is a Brazilian citizen and was refused a travel visa last year.  I ended up traveling to Brazil and spent a month visiting her.  Now I want her to visit me in the USA.  Does anyone have any tips to help her obtain the travel visa approval?

Comment: @choster For a moment, I thought this had been migrated from another SE site but it seems that your mind was on other things. :-)

Comment: The tip is to fix whatever issues caused the application to be rejected. If you want us to help you with that, you'll need to tell us the exact reasons for rejection.